# Delete/unset from a global array using a function / method

Tags: php, arrays

I have an GLOBAL array that keeps all the configurations, it looks like this:

```
$_SOME_ARRAY = array(
                'some_setting' => array(
                                    'some_value' => '1',
                                    'other' => 'value'
                                ),  
                'something_else' => 1,
            );
```

How can I delete keys from this array, using some function like:

`deleteFromArray('some_setting/other')`

I have tried different things, but can't seem to find a way, to delete it without manually calling `unset($_SOME_ARRAY['some_setting']['other'])`

### EDIT

I have tried working on with it. The only solution I see so far, is by "rebuilding" the original array, by looping through each value and verify. The progress:

```
        public static function delete($path) {
            global $_EDU_SETUP;

            $exploded_path = explode('/', $path);

            $newConfig = array();

            $delete = false;

            foreach($exploded_path as $bit) {

                if(!$delete) {
                    $loop = $_EDU_SETUP;
                } else {
                    $loop = $delete;
                }

                foreach($loop as $key => $value) {

                    if($key == $bit) {
                        echo 'found first: ' . $key . '<br />'; // debugging

                        if(!$delete) {
                            $delete = $_EDU_SETUP[$key];
                        } else {
                            $delete = $delete[$key];
                        }
                    } else {
                        $newConfig[$key] = $value;
                    }
                }
            }

            $_EDU_SETUP = $newConfig;
        }
```

The array could look like this:

```
$array = array(
    'a' => array(
        'a',
        'b',
        'c'
    ),
    'b' => array(
        'a',
        'b',
        'c' => array(
            'a',
            'b',
            'c' => array(
                'a'
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

And to delete $array['b']['c'] you would write `Config::delete('b/c');` - BUT: It deletes whole B. It is only supposed to delete C.

Any ideas?

Comment: why don't you just split the sting with explode and use the params in your deleteFromArray function ? by the way, you could use `$_SESSION` :)

Comment: does this array has only 2 demensions ?

Comment: No - unlimited amount

Comment: could you post a array with the result your trying to achieve ? :)

Answer (score 1):

This what you can do, assuming the array has 2 levels of data.

```
 $_SOME_ARRAY = array(
                    'some_setting' => array(
                                        'some_value' => '1',
                                        'other' => 'value'
                                    ),  
                    'something_else' => 1,
                );

function deleteFromArray($param){
    global $_SOME_ARRAY ;
    $param_values = explode("/",$param);
    if(count($param_values) == 2 ){
        unset($_SOME_ARRAY[$param_values[0]][$param_values[1]]);
    }else{
        unset($_SOME_ARRAY[$param_values[0]]);
    }
}

deleteFromArray('some_setting/other');
print_r($_SOME_ARRAY);
```

You can modify the function to add more strict rules by checking if the key exists before doing unset using the function `array_key_exists()`

Comment: Well - I'd like not to assume anything, as the config array should be able to be as big as needed.

Comment: I meant 2D array i.e. `array['one']['two']`

Comment: I have edited my post with additional information.. Maybe that will help.

Answer (score 1):

how do you like this ?

```
$_SESSION = $_SOME_ARRAY; // Btw it should be session from beginning...

function deleteFromArray($string)
{

    $array = explode("/",$sting);

    foreach($array as $arrA)
    {
        foreach($array as $arrB)
        {
            unset($_SESSION[$arrA][$arrB]);
        }
    }
}
```

now you could delete more than one entry like

```
deleteFromArray('some_setting/some_value/a_other_value')
```

but take care of using dim1array names in dim2array...

of corse you could add more foreach or make a recursiv function out of it to get deep in the array

Comment: I think we're getting close! However, I don't see how this solution could work with a multidimensional array, like: `delete/this/deep/value/in/config`.

Answer (score 0):

do you want to delete particular array using a unique index(like a primary id)?, i would use a for loop to look for that particular index then delete that array...E.g delete array where the index = 1 , pls check above

```
foreach ($_SOME_ARRAY as $a => $key)//get all child arrays of '$_SOME_ARRAY '
{
   foreach($Key as $b => $key2)//get values of the child arrays
   {
        if($Key[0] == 1)// if the index at[0] equals 1
        {
            unset($arr[$a][$b]); //delete that array
        } 
   }
}
```

Comment: i made some edits to your post, even if looks like a kind of copy paste to my psot ^^

Comment: lol. not really, i had to code something lyk these sometime last week aswell for a shopping cart m creating, a user needs to delete a product that i saved into a session array, bt thanks man